# How can I add images on the Angular 2/4 material design select component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using the [material angular select component](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview). I can see the icons when I click on the selector but the problem is when I choose an option it only shows the value and not the icons.

At the moment the code is rewriting the `<md-option>` removing the `<img>` tag and adding the `{{bodyStyle.viewValue}}`

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="form-control form-control--center">                 
 <md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedBodystyle" floatPlaceholder="never" name="bodyStyle">
    <md-option *ngFor="let bodyStyle of bodyStyles" [value]="bodyStyle.value">
        <img src="{{bodyStyle.icon}}" alt="{{bodyStyle.viewValue}}">
            {{bodyStyle.viewValue}}

    </md-option>
 </md-select>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  selectedBodystyle: string;
  bodyStyles = [
    { value: 'Mercedez' , viewValue: 'Mercedez', icon: "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/transport/" },
    { value: 'Ferrari'  , viewValue: 'Ferrari' , icon: "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/transport/" },
    { value: 'BMW'      , viewValue: 'BMW'     , icon: "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/transport/" }
  ];
```

---

**Update**

I tried to add the image in the `viewValue` attribute like

```
{ value: 'Ferrari'  , viewValue: '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/transport/" alt="Ferrari">Ferrari' }
```

but it loads the html in plain text it doesn't show the image after being selected

This is what it shows after select an option it removes the image it shows only the only the content from the `viewValue`

[image]

Comment: There is an open PR that will simplify this for you https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/3341. I'm not sure it's possible without component factory and some trickery

Comment: I'm been trying to some How pass the image in the <md-option [value]="here"> because it's this what it's selected..let me check your link..thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update (Showing icon next to md-menu beta.8):**

You can put a separate `<img>` tag next to `md-menu` and use the image `src` from selected menu item. Please note, for that, the `value` needs to bind with whole object, not the object property only.

html:

```
<div class="form-control form-control--center">  
<i *ngIf="selectedIcon"><img [src]="selectedIcon" alt="selectedIcon" style="margin-bottom: -15px"></i>
 <md-select [(ngModel)]="selectedBodystyle" 
            floatPlaceholder="never" 
            name="bodyStyle"
            (change)="optionSelected($event)">
    <md-option *ngFor="let bodyStyle of bodyStyles" [value]="bodyStyle">
        <img [src]="bodyStyle.icon" [alt]="bodyStyle.viewValue">
            {{bodyStyle.viewValue}}
    </md-option>
 </md-select>
</div>
```

ts:

```
export class SelectFormExample {
  selectedBodystyle: string;
  selectedIcon;
  bodyStyles = [
    { value: 'Mercedez' , viewValue: 'Mercedez', icon: "http://lorempixel.com/40/40/transport/" },
    { value: 'Ferrari'  , viewValue: 'Ferrari' , icon: "http://lorempixel.com/30/30/transport/" },
    { value: 'BMW'      , viewValue: 'BMW'     , icon: "http://lorempixel.com/50/50/transport/" }
  ];

  optionSelected(event){
    // console.log(event.value.icon);
    this.selectedIcon = event.value.icon;
  }
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/uOjWi02nZAAbaW8YJonN?p=preview)

**Original:**

Use `[src]="bodyStyle.icon"` instead of `src="{{bodyStyle.icon}}"`

I suggest doing the same for `alt="{{bodyStyle.viewValue}}"` too. Change to `[alt]="bodyStyle.viewValue"`

Comment: my code works exactly like your plunker... what I need is to show the icon after being selected

Comment: I updated the question, I tried some things but didn't work

Comment: As Will said, material2 doesn't have an easy way of showing image for selected option. But, I have created a work around for you. Check the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uOjWi02nZAAbaW8YJonN?p=preview) again and let me know if it works for you...

Comment: this solved my question and it makes sense what you did.. I dont know why it looks like your plunkr is not working it changes the text but not the image... I changed the lorempixel images and works fine. if you can make a new answer with the plunkr code I will mark as a solve.. and hopefully it would help other

Comment: Glad that it solved your problem. I have updated the answer. Also, just wanted to note that, the images weren't changing, because they all had the same image `src`. I have updated the plunker with different `src` for each item, and now it change for each selection.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shot in the dark but try

```
<img [src]="bodyStyle.icon"...
```

Comment: I tried this option the problem is after select one option it shows the value and not the image